# dplyr drop values based on difference

Tags: r, dplyr, dt

I have a table like this

```
   Stimuli Subject Block TChosen Percentage
   <fct>   <fct>   <fct>   <int> <chr>     
 1 1       1       13          7 14.29%    
 2 2       1       13         18 36.73%    
 3 3       1       13         24 48.98%    
 4 1       2       13          3 6.12%     
 5 2       2       13         15 30.61%    
 6 3       2       13         31 63.27%    
 7 13      100     13         13 26.53%    
 8 14      100     13         11 22.45%    
 9 15      100     13         25 51.02%    
10 1       1002    13          9 18.37%
```

Per subject per block, I would like to drop rows where the percentage is within 10% of another entry. So in this case above entry 7 and 8 would be dropped.

Desired output

```
   Stimuli Subject Block TChosen Percentage
   <fct>   <fct>   <fct>   <int> <chr>     
 1 1       1       13          7 14.29%    
 2 2       1       13         18 36.73%    
 3 3       1       13         24 48.98%    
 4 1       2       13          3 6.12%     
 5 2       2       13         15 30.61%    
 6 3       2       13         31 63.27%       
 7 15      100     13         25 51.02%    
 8 1       1002    13          9 18.37%
```

Thank you!

Comment: why is row 9 kept? another entry or next entry?

Comment: This problem quite complex. The results might depend on the orders of dropping (or orders of rows if we proceed row by row).

Comment: I agree that this could produce different results based on how you sort the data (assuming you use Ronak's lag/lead code). It would be useful to specify whether it would be preferable to keep the highest or lowest (or other) value when there are multiples in your range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Percentage = readr::parse_number(Percentage)) %>%
  arrange(Subject, Block, Percentage) %>%
  group_by(Subject, Block) %>%
  filter(Percentage - lag(Percentage, default = -Inf) > 10 & 
         lead(Percentage, default = Inf) - Percentage > 10) %>%
  ungroup

#  Stimuli Subject Block TChosen Percentage
#    <int>   <int> <int>   <int>      <dbl>
#1       1       1    13       7      14.3 
#2       2       1    13      18      36.7 
#3       3       1    13      24      49.0 
#4       1       2    13       3       6.12
#5       2       2    13      15      30.6 
#6       3       2    13      31      63.3 
#7      15     100    13      25      51.0 
#8       1    1002    13       9      18.4
```

Convert `Percentage` to numbers and keep rows which are greater than 10% of both their previous and next value within each `Subject` and `Block`.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Stimuli = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 1L), Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
1002L), Block = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L), TChosen = c(7L, 18L, 24L, 3L, 15L, 31L, 13L, 11L, 25L, 
9L), Percentage = c("14.29%", "36.73%", "48.98%", "6.12%", "30.61%", 
"63.27%", "26.53%", "22.45%", "51.02%", "18.37%")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: This might not work if in one group you have a percentage sequence like 10%, 50%, 12%. Perhaps this could be addressed by sorting by percentage within each group?

Comment: That's right. Also while correcting this I realised my previous method was incorrect. I have addressed both the issues. Thanks.